# Computing a point having distances from 2 points respectively

Tags: geometry

I want to compute a point $p$ which has distances $d1$ and $d2$ from points $q1$ and $q2$ respectively.
As I wanted a general answer, I used Maxima inputting the following script ,

$solve($
$[sqrt((num1-x)^2+(num2-y)^2)=num3,$
$sqrt((num4-x)^2+(num5-y)^2)=num6]$
$,[x,y]);$

Where all variables of the format $num$_ were constants in my mind and $p=(x,y)$.
I expected an output like , x= ... ; y= ..... .
Though,the output was just an empty bracket $[]$.
Is the script mathematically wrong or lacking some information or
 just a problem of the software ,Maxima?

(*Optionally, I am glad if you let me know a script which works well.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There won't be a point satisfying your problem for every $q_1$, $q_2$, $d_1$, and $d_2$. Have you tried your script with values that you know have a solution?

Comment: @AustinMohr: Supposing I understand your comment correctly,p=(0,0),q1=(1,0),q2=(-1,0),d1=d2=1.And the result was the same , just an empty bracket $[ ]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AustinMohr noted, this problem has no solution in general case (i.e., for arbitrary values of the inputs). It will have a solution (there exists $p$) if and only if anyone of the following two conditions is satisfied:

1. $\quad d_0=|q_1q_2|=d_1+d_2$,
2. $\quad d_0=|d_1-d_2|$,
3. $\quad d_0, d_1, d_2$ are the sides of  a triangle which is true iff $d_i\le s~\forall i=1,2,3; s=\text{ ``half-perimeter" }=\frac{d_0+d_1+d_2}{2}$

**Case1:** In this case $p$ is the (unique) lies inside $|q_1q_2|$ and is given by $p=\frac{d_2.q_1+d_1.q_2}{d_1+d_2}$.

**Case2:** In this case $p$ lies on the extended $|q_1q_2|$ and is given by $p=\frac{d_2.q_1-d_1.q_2}{d_2-d_1}$.

**Case3:** $p$ is the two intersecting points of the two circles $C_1(q_1,d_1)$ and $C_2(q_2,d_2)$.

---

**Edit:** Yes, $p$ is always the intersecting point(s) of the two circles $C_1(q_1,d_1)$ and $C_2(q_2,d_2)$. I think the result holds in higher dimensions as well.

Comment: Case3 may be considered as the general solution...? May be someone will clarify things better.

Comment: No, the three cases together form the general solution.  The set of solutions (for two distinct circles) has either zero, one, or two points.

Comment: @JackManey: No, (the answer in) case3 is the general answer. Please see the Edited part of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking in purely geometrical terms, you're given two circles $C_1$ and $C_2$ with distinct centers, and you want to find the points of intersection of the circles (here, the points $q_1$ and $q_2$ are the centers and the radii are $d_1$ and $d_2$).  By [Book III, Proposition 10 of Euclid's Elements](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIII/propIII10.html), circles that are not concentric intersect in at most two points.  Therefore your solution set will consist of either zero (in your case above), one, or two points.

Comment: You can ease computations a bit by first computing the radical line of the two circles, and then checking if the line intersects any of the two circles...

Comment: @J.M. - The point of my answer, though, is to show in purely geometrical terms--without direct computation--that the solution set the OP wants contains at most two points.  It's merely another way to think about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maple code that calculates coordinates $(x,y)$ of the point $P$ :

[image]

The second variant of the code is the same as this above,only difference is that you should change a sign $+$ into sign $-$ in front of the $sqrt$